# FileNotFoundException on MyProject.resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, image, embedded-resource

I am trying to add an image to a button (C# Winform, VS2010).  I have added the resource by Adding Existing Item in the Resources.resx file.  I then assign my image to the button and all appears well.  When i run my program i get:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'BmsReplayAnalysis.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

in this code:

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap play1 {
    get {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("play1", resourceCulture); <-- DIES HERE
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Okay i figured out what was going on. I have an assemblyresolveEventHandler in my code. I had a catch all else statement that pointed the Myassembly.resources.dll to the wrong location

Answer (score 1):

When you just give it a name of a file, when you run it, it looks for it in the folder that it is running out of. If you are running in debug mode, it will look for play1 inside the debug folder. if its not there its an error.

Comment: So what would be the proper way to implement this?  I thought it would have been embedded in my executable?

Comment: to my knowledge it won't embed itself in your program. the only way is to give it a full path to the image and keep the image there. or keep the image in the same path as the executable

Comment: If that is the case, then the term embedded resource is a misnomer.  I don't really think that is the case?

Comment: i am fixing my 2010 and will try it and check on 2008 in the meantime

Comment: I don't know. I can't replicate the error. i go to resources and add an existing file. give it image.jpg, go to form1[design] attach local resource image.jpg to the button i want and it appears on the button. if i delete the image in its location it does still work in the form, if i delete local resources then i get errors instead of unhandledexception

Comment: Okay i figured out what was going on.  I have an assemblyresolveEventHandler in my code.  I had a catch all else statement that pointed the Myassembly.resources.dll to the wrong location.